# Append zeros to array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, append

I want to create an array that initially has these values:

```
[[[0,0,0,0]], [[0,0,0,0]]]
```

Then appending zeros to the next row:

```
[[[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]], [[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]]
```

and again similarly appending zeros to the next row in a loop:

```
[[[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], ...], [[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], ...]]
```

How can I do this with python?
I tried

```
import numpy, pandas
x = numpy.array([[[0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0]]])
numpy.append(x[0], [[0, 0, 0, 0]], axis=0)
print(x)
```

Comment: Each operation creates a new array, with lots of copying. Do you really want that?  Why not just make the array with correct shape at the start?  And read the functions carefully.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for might be [`numpy.insert(arr, obj, values, axis=None)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html#numpy-insert) to "Insert values along the given axis before the given indices". In your case, in the array A (`arr`) you want to insert zeros (`values`) along axis 1 (`axis=1`). If you want to insert the element at the beginning, specify the position 0 (`obj`), but if you want it at the end use -1:

```
>>> A = np.array([[[0,0,0,0]], [[0,0,0,0]]])
>>> A.shape
(2, 1, 4)
>>> B = np.insert(A, 1, 0, axis=1)
>>> B.shape
(2, 2, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [160]: x = numpy.array([[[0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0]]])
In [161]: x
Out[161]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0]]])
In [162]: x.shape
Out[162]: (2, 1, 4)
```

Let's be clear what you start with - note the shape!

Your append attempt:

```
In [163]: np.append(x[0], [[0, 0, 0, 0]], axis=0)
Out[163]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [164]: _.shape
Out[164]: (2, 4)
```

It makes a NEW array - `x[0]` is (1,4) array, and you join another (1,4) to make a (2,4).  `np.append` when used like this is just `np.concatenate`.  Read, and reread, the docs if necessary.

It did not change `x`.  `np.append` is NOT a list append clone.

```
In [165]: x
Out[165]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

If you must work incrementally, use list and list append. Arrays have a fixed size, so 'growing' them requires making a new array.